# How to make back button on action bar clickable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, back-button

i succeeded in adding a back button to the action bar of an activity but when clicked nothing happens here is the code

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

all i want to know is how to make the button clickable (to go back) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should ask Google, it's your friend. Questions like that will be mark down and probably closed like duplicate.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //do what you want
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry please can you use my code and explain this (like paste it for me ) cos it's not still working or maybe i'm doing something wrong @Yupi

Comment: You should paste that method below your onCreate method and if your MenuItem is in red that means you have to `import android.view.MenuItem;`

Comment: uhh... The back button... still no clickable

Comment: Did you see my last comment and copy and paste the code with onBackPressed method?